# Why Locking in Go much slower than Java? Lot's of time spent in Mutex.Lock() Mutex.Unlock()

Tags: go, locking, profiling, benchmarking, futex

I've written a small Go library ([go-patan](https://github.com/toefel18/go-patan)) that collects a running min/max/avg/stddev of certain variables. I compared it to an equivalent Java implementation ([patan](https://github.com/toefel18/patan)), and to my surprise the Java implementation is much faster. I would like to understand why.

The library basically consists of a simple data store with a lock that serializes reads and writes. This is a snippet of the code:

```
type Store struct {
   durations map[string]*Distribution
   counters  map[string]int64
   samples   map[string]*Distribution

   lock *sync.Mutex
}

func (store *Store) addSample(key string, value int64) {
  store.addToStore(store.samples, key, value)
}

func (store *Store) addDuration(key string, value int64) {
  store.addToStore(store.durations, key, value)
}

func (store *Store) addToCounter(key string, value int64) {
  store.lock.Lock()
  defer store.lock.Unlock()
  store.counters[key] = store.counters[key] + value
}

func (store *Store) addToStore(destination map[string]*Distribution, key string, value int64) {
  store.lock.Lock()
  defer store.lock.Unlock()
  distribution, exists := destination[key]
  if !exists {
    distribution = NewDistribution()
    destination[key] = distribution
  }
  distribution.addSample(value)
}
```

I've benchmarked the GO and Java implementations ([go-benchmark-gist](https://gist.github.com/toefel18/96edac8f57f9ad8a4f9a86d83e726aec), [java-benchmark-gist](https://gist.github.com/toefel18/9def55a8c3c53c79a4488c29c66f31e5)) and Java wins by far, but I don't understand why:

```
Go Results:
10 threads with 20000 items took 133 millis
100 threads with 20000 items took 1809 millis
1000 threads with 20000 items took 17576 millis
10 threads with 200000 items took 1228 millis
100 threads with 200000 items took 17900 millis

Java Results:
10 threads with 20000 items takes 89 millis
100 threads with 20000 items takes 265 millis
1000 threads with 20000 items takes 2888 millis  
10 threads with 200000 items takes 311 millis
100 threads with 200000 items takes 3067 millis
```

I've profiled the program with the Go's pprof and generated a call graph [call-graph](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/toefel18/96edac8f57f9ad8a4f9a86d83e726aec/raw/c1ff6452abaefe49c3c688b3d07e4574cbe77264/call-graph.png). This shows that it basically spends all the time in sync.(*Mutex).Lock() and sync.(*Mutex).Unlock().

The Top20 calls according to the profiler:

```
(pprof) top20
59110ms of 73890ms total (80.00%)
Dropped 22 nodes (cum <= 369.45ms)
Showing top 20 nodes out of 65 (cum >= 50220ms)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    8900ms 12.04% 12.04%     8900ms 12.04%  runtime.futex
    7270ms  9.84% 21.88%     7270ms  9.84%  runtime/internal/atomic.Xchg
    7020ms  9.50% 31.38%     7020ms  9.50%  runtime.procyield
    4560ms  6.17% 37.56%     4560ms  6.17%  sync/atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32
    4400ms  5.95% 43.51%     4400ms  5.95%  runtime/internal/atomic.Xadd
    4210ms  5.70% 49.21%    22040ms 29.83%  runtime.lock
    3650ms  4.94% 54.15%     3650ms  4.94%  runtime/internal/atomic.Cas
    3260ms  4.41% 58.56%     3260ms  4.41%  runtime/internal/atomic.Load
    2220ms  3.00% 61.56%    22810ms 30.87%  sync.(*Mutex).Lock
    1870ms  2.53% 64.10%     1870ms  2.53%  runtime.osyield
    1540ms  2.08% 66.18%    16740ms 22.66%  runtime.findrunnable
    1430ms  1.94% 68.11%     1430ms  1.94%  runtime.freedefer
    1400ms  1.89% 70.01%     1400ms  1.89%  sync/atomic.AddUint32
    1250ms  1.69% 71.70%     1250ms  1.69%  github.com/toefel18/go-patan/statistics/lockbased.(*Distribution).addSample
    1240ms  1.68% 73.38%     3140ms  4.25%  runtime.deferreturn
    1070ms  1.45% 74.83%     6520ms  8.82%  runtime.systemstack
    1010ms  1.37% 76.19%     1010ms  1.37%  runtime.newdefer
    1000ms  1.35% 77.55%     1000ms  1.35%  runtime.mapaccess1_faststr
     950ms  1.29% 78.83%    15660ms 21.19%  runtime.semacquire
     860ms  1.16% 80.00%    50220ms 67.97%  main.Benchmrk.func1
```

Can someone explain why locking in Go seems to be so much slower than in Java, what am I doing wrong? I've also written a channel based implementation in Go, but that is even slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also posted this question on the [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/I-p5vmyln9c/discussion) group. The reply from  [Jesper Louis Andersen](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/I-p5vmyln9c/OfxO0nZBBgAJ) explains quite well that Java uses synchronization optimization techniques such as lock escape analysis/lock elision and lock coarsening.

Java JIT might be taking the lock and allowing multiple updates at once within the lock to increase performance. I ran the Java benchmark with `-Djava.compiler=NONE` which gave dramatic performance, but is not a fair comparison.

I assume that many of these optimization techniques have less impact in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to avoid `defer` in tiny functions that need high performance since it is expensive. In most other cases, there is no need to avoid it since the cost of `defer` is outweighed by the code around it.

I'd also recommend using `lock sync.Mutex` instead of using a pointer. The pointer creates a slight amount of extra work for the programmer (initialisation, `nil` bugs), and a slight amount of extra work for the garbage collector.

Comment: using explicit locking indeed results in much better performance. I've also the *sync.Mutex to sync.Mutex. I'm kind of disappointed that defer statements aren't optimized away if the compiler can detect this, but the catch is probably that it's hard for the compiler to detect (I can imagine extra code is required to execute defers when unwinding the stack during a panic)

Comment: You're right, the 2 forms aren't equivalent due to panic handling. Hence its hard to optimise it away entirely. Defer will be significantly faster in Go 1.8, so you might want to revisit after it is released early next year.